# JS: get/set table style in ASP Comet application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, comet

I've got ASP web site with some table updated by the use of long polling. And I want to use jquery plugin DataTables to that table. So, I initiate it and everything is fine. But...
1. I make some actions to the table (e.g. sorting).
2. Server pushes data to the web page and reinitializes plugin.
3. No sorting that I've made in step 1.

The only solution I see is to get table style before data refresh and set this style after. So I'm looking for some ready solution to do this (i'm newby in js) or may be somebody will help me with to solve problem in other way.
Any links or advice will be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb. I used repeater and BindData() to fill the table.
DataTables has its own method to obtain data from server. So all I've needed is just to put code for filling table in the same script where long polling is called.